# RecyclerView views updated even when there is no difference based on DiffUtil?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using ListAdapter with a DiffUtil.ItemCallback and I have made the DiffUtil callback methods return true for all items to inspect its behavior. And it seems that the RecyclerView views are still getting updated and showing the new result ('D', 'E', 'F'). I did not expect this, Shouldn't the RecyclerView only update views/items that have changed?

**Adapter:**

```
class ItemsAdapter : ListAdapter<Item, ItemViewHolder>(ItemDiff) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        return ItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}

object ItemDiff : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Item, newItem: Item): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}

class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val tvName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)

    fun bind(item: Item) {
        tvName.text = item.name
    }
}

data class Item(val name: String)
```

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private val adapter = ItemsAdapter()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    rvItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvItems.adapter = adapter

    adapter.submitList(listOf(Item("A"), Item("B"), Item("C")))

    adapter.submitList(listOf(Item("D"), Item("E"), Item("F")))
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `submitList()` replace the list? In which case the behaviour is as expected

Comment: @IvanWooll
**From the Android documentation:**

Submits a new list to be diffed, and displayed. If a list is already being displayed, a diff will be computed on a background thread, which will dispatch Adapter.notifyItem events on the main thread._

Comment: Try submitting second list from a button click or something, I think issue is you're submitting two lists at once and internal differ of `ListAdapter` discards the first list without running any diff.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and it seems like it was a concurrency issue, Since I was calling the submitList method twice and ListAdapter calculates the diff on the background thread.

To test this I changed my activity code to the following and the list was **not** updated.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private val adapter = ItemsAdapter()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    rvItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvItems.adapter = adapter

    adapter.submitList(listOf(Item("A"), Item("B"), Item("C")))

    thread {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      runOnUiThread {
        adapter.submitList(listOf(Item("D"), Item("E"), Item("F")))
        Toast.makeText(this, "second submitList", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
    }
  }
}
```